# Is this a wrong way of finding the leap years?

Tags: python, leap-year

I am a beginner, learning Python from ["Python Programming MOOC 2022"](https://programming-22.mooc.fi/part-2/3-combining-conditions). They are asking me to write a code which asks for a year and then says whether it is a leap year or not. The problem is that when I write the code, the website says its wrong, as it has an infinite loop.

```
# Write your solution here
y=int(input("Please type in a year:"))
if y%4==0:
    if y%100==0 :
        if y%400==0:
            print("That year is a leap year.")
        else:
            print("That year is not a leap year.")
    else:
        print("That year is a leap year.")
else:
    print("That year is not a leap year.")
```

I cant really understand where the infinite loop is.
I'll be really thankful if you tell me what's wrong with this code so that I can fix it.

I ran this code on some online ides and it worked without any problem. I cant understand whether I am wrong or the website is facing some issues...

Comment: There's no loop in that code, so an infinite loop is impossible. Is there more code you're not showing?

Comment: Is your code being tested with "bad" inputs? For example, what happens if the user inputs "Thursday" instead of "2003"?

Comment: You probably meant `if y%100 != 0` ? Years that are divisible by 100 are not leap years, only those divisible by 400. https://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Leap-Years

Comment: To remove redundancy, try: `is_leap_year = y % 4 == 0 and (y % 100 != 0 or y % 400 == 0)`.